# My logic app continuously checks trigger every second

Tags: azure-logic-apps

My app is checking to see if blob storage has changed.  If it has changed it will send an email and work as intended.  However if the blob storage has not changed it will continuously check the trigger till it has.

[My app contentiously check for triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy799.png)[How the logic app is set up. The other 2 parts work fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Uqk.png)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have Recurrence trigger?

Comment: This is the normal behavior of a blob trigger (pull mode) have a look at eventgrid (push mode)

Comment: Is your logic app triggered by a Recurrence trigger or Blob trigger?